# Flask: Custom Error handler resulting in TypeError: isinstance() arg 2

Tags: python, flask, typeerror

I have an issue using Flask and creating a custom error handler. I want to offload my error handling to a separate class and have followed the documentation here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/apierrors/

Upon testing my new error handler the following message is returned.

```
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a class, type, or tuple of classes and types
```

I believe the above error message is coming directly from this check in Flask: https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/flask/app.py#L1407 but I don't understand the actual problem or how to fix it.

The custom error class is:

```
class ErrorHandler(Exception):
    status_code = 400

    def __init__(self, message, status_code=None, payload=None):
        Exception.__init__(self)
        self.message = message
        if status_code is not None:
            self.status_code = status_code
        self.payload = payload

    def to_dict(self):
        rv = dict(self.payload or ())
        rv['message'] = self.message
        return rv
```

and the code that is being run to call this class is:

```
@app.errorhandler(ErrorHandler)
def bad_request(error):
    response = jsonify(error.to_dict())
    response.status_code = error.status_code
    return response

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def testing():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        raise ErrorHandler('test', 400)
    elif request.methods == 'POST':
         pass
    else:
         pass
```

**SOLVED:**

Changed my imports from

```
import ErrorHandler
```

to

```
from ErrorHandler import ErrorHandler
```

Comment: Your Exception subclass has the name `ErrorHanlder`, note the transposition of the `d` and `l`. The `ErrorHandler` you registered with `@app.errorhandler()` is then likely to *not* be a type but something else entirely.

Comment: Oops, I'll fix that but it's still not the issue I am afraid.

Comment: The exception is caused because whatever you passed into `@app.errorhandler()` is not a class, so `isinstance(thrownexception, ErrorHandler)` fails with that error.

Comment: Thank you. It should be from ErrorHandler import ErrorHandler.

Comment: See, this is why PEP-8 recommends you use lower-case names for modules, camel-case for classes. :-)

Comment: Thank you Martijn, I've change my classes and modules to reflect such.

Answer (score 0):

The exception indicates that what you are passing to the `@app.errorhandler()` decorator is *not a class*.

The `isinstance()` test is given the exception raised (`ErrorHandler('test', 400)` in your case), and whatever you passed to `@app.errorhandler()`. The exception tells you that latter value is not a class:

```
>>> class Foo(Exception): pass
... 
>>> isinstance(Foo(), Foo)
True
>>> isinstance(Foo(), 'something else')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a class, type, or tuple of classes and types
```

Double-check and triple-check you have the right object there.